# Python SSL FTP connection timing out

Tags: python, ssl, ftp, timeout

I'm trying to get a connection established to a FTP server with SSL from within Python (v3.3.0).  But I keep getting a timeout.  I am **NOT** using port 990 as the SSL port (paranoid).  Would that be the cause of this problem? And if so, how do I specify the port I am using?

Here's my script:

```
    from ftplib import FTP
    from ftplib import FTP_TLS

    ftps = FTP_TLS('ip address')

    ftps.auth()

    ftps.sendcmd('USER uname') 
    ftps.sendcmd('PASS password')

    ftps.prot_p()
    ftps.retrlines('LIST')

    ftps.close()
```

And here is the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Scrpit name removed for posting", line 12, in <module>
    ftps.retrlines('LIST')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 767, in retrlines
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 381, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 742, in ntransfercmd
    conn, size = FTP.ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ftplib.py", line 343, in ntransfercmd
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 424, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 415, in create_connection
   sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

> > > 

any advice would be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 4):

After looking at the [ftplib source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/ftplib.py), it doesn't seem to want to use any port but 21.

I think you should be able to work around this, something like

```
import ftplib

ftplib.FTP.port = 995     # or whatever port you are using
ftps = ftplib.FTP_TLS('hostname', 'user', 'pwd')
ftps.retrlines('LIST')
```

Comment: Thank you - after googling for a resolution I finally found this answer which fixes the issue. I can get a directory listing now!

Answer (score 0):

Set the port through the `connect`

```
import ftplib

ftps = ftplib.FTP_TLS()
ftps.connect ('hostname', 991)
```

Comment: I'm using the astandard port 21 for FTP, but not the standard 990 for SSL so how would I set the SSL port ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, using the method above connects to the designated port.

Comment: IN order to isolate the problem, I changed the SSL port to the default 990, but I still have the same timeout problem.  I verified the port change took by manually connecting via Filezilla client